# Angular Error_for_TS2554 Expected 0 arguments, but got 3

Tags: angular, rxjs6, angular8

Created a generic httpServie for all calls.

```
  export class HttpApiService {
    constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
    public getData<T>(url: string, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<T> | Observable<any> {
        this.customReqOptions = this.getHeaders(headers);
        return this.httpClient.get(`${this.endPoint}${url}`, { headers: this.customReqOptions});
    }
  }
```

Calling it from UserSevice

```
export class UserService {
    constructor(private httpApi: HttpApiService) {
    }

    public getUsers(): Observable<any>{
      return this.httpApi.getData('users')
      .pipe(
        tap((res) => {console.log('res,',res)}),
        publishReplay(1),
        refCount()
      );
    }
}
```

The pipe () one giving error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 3.

Created a code for ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/anglearn

Even when run in VS code getting same issue
[image]

What I am missing ?
Although using the latest version @angular: v8, rxjs: 6.4 using ngcli.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getData` method like this:

```
public getData<T>(url: string, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<T> {
        this.customReqOptions = this.getHeaders(headers);
        return this.httpClient.get<T>(`${this.endPoint}${url}`, { headers: this.customReqOptions});
    }
```

For some reasons, TS compiler is not liking the generic method to return `Observable<any>`. NOTICE - there is no run time error.

See the working stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/anglearn-tezbyk?file=src/app/common/httpApi.service.ts

Comment: Thanks. got wired Compile time error in local VS ERROR in 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
 Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'T'.
 The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?  Got Different Solution.. Pasting below

Comment: Technically ‘any’ is fine as at the run time it plan vanilla JS. But overloaded version is also absolutely fine. It is design choice and maintenance. Personally, I would stick to generic as it is just a typing and it is same as any at least on typescript side.

Answer (score 0):

Adding all Signature/Overloading

```
    public getData(url: string, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<any>;
    public getData<T>(url: string, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<T>;
    public getData<T>(url: string, headers?: HttpHeaders): Observable<T> | Observable<any> {
        this.customReqOptions = this.getHeaders(headers);
        return this.httpClient.get(`${this.endPoint}${url}`, { headers: this.customReqOptions});
    }
```

No Issue either in VScode(Run/Compile)..Not sure weather its a good practice or not.